# "Es mochte nichts helfen"

Tags: german-to-english, idiom

Ich versuche zu verstehen, was eine gute Übersetzung (ins Englische) für "Es mochte nichts helfen" wäre.  Ich habe aus [Duden.de](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/moegen) diesen Ausdruck gefunden (unter Punkt c).  Würde "It couldn't be helped" die richtige Gesinnung erfassen?

Comment: Can you provide more context? The best translation will depend on the context.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  I'm trying to understand what Duden means, and that is all the context I'm given.

Comment: I should say, I assumed maybe this was some kind of colorful expression that could be mapped to a similar one in the UK/US countryside.  But maybe that's not the case.

Comment: The common English idiom I'm familiar with is "it wouldn't help". Recall the *wollen / möchten* dichotomy (*wollen* is proscribed for the desire of wishes). It may be a past tense subjunctive, while \*möchten would be a reanalyzed infinitive (actually an incomplete verb) from the Konjunktiv form of *mögen* (pret. *mochte*). Whether "wouldn't" is a good translation would be besides the point--this is not the English stackexchange--so I'm not posting an answer. Some Konjunktiv II forms are indistinguishable from preterite like this, so it is a well complicated question, too (cp. En. *were*).

Comment: In other words, yes, your translation is pretty close, but if I guess correctly, your "it" is the passive benefactor, whereas this "Es" is the auxiliary agent of the help. Which is so much the two sides of the same coin, especially wherever it is actually an indefinite dummy pronoun, that I would consider it far from incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vorausgeschickt: die Formulierung wirkt archaisch oder möglicherweise regional, im üblichen Sprachgebrauch wird man nicht oft auf sie treffen.

Der Zusammenhang wäre hilfreich (siehe Kommentar von PMF), denn prinzipiell gibt es zwei Möglichkeiten, was gemeint ist:

*Es* (ein konkretes "es", das vorher näher ausgeführt wurde, als Subjekt des Satzes) mochte *nichts helfen* ("nichts" als Zusatz zu "helfen", in der Bedeutung von "nicht einmal ein wenig helfen");
dann wäre eine mögliche Übersetzung "It was of no avail"

oder

Es mochte *nichts* helfen ("Nichts" als das Subjekt des Satzes; ausgesprochen wäre das Wort dann betont)
Übersetzung so wie von Niranam vorgeschlagen - "Nothing was of any use"/"Nothing helped"

Comment: Third possibility, *nichts* as relative pronoun (the way *nicht* is derived from "ni" + "was"), thus a transitive object (a) niemandem helfen, or b) mit nichten). Also, I suspect in some dialects a participle-izing "zu" would help clarify the syntax, *Es vermochte nicht zu helfen*.... Interessanter Ansatz. Mir war gar nicht bewusst, dass dies neben der Verbform überhaupt in Frage stand.

Answer (score 4):

Die Antwort steht im Grunde schon auf der von dir verlinkten Duden-Seite: der Gebrauch ist landschaftlich, also nicht Standard, sondern nur in manchen Gegenden so zu hören.

Die Bedeutung von „mögen“ ist hier: können, imstande sein, die Möglichkeit haben oder enthalten (mit Infinitiv als Modalverb) – ganz so, wie in der Standardsprache „vermögen".

Und wie es genau zu verstehen ist, steht auch dort:
es mochte nichts helfen (nichts half)

Die Bedeutung ist also: Nichts half – oder eben:„ Nichts vermochte zu helfen": Nothing did any good / Nothing was of any use.